# How to solve generalized recurrence relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, recurrence-relations

An usual recurrence relation can be written as:

$$a_{n} = \sum_k c_ka_{n-k}$$
or alternatively:
$$a_{n} - \sum_k c_ka_{n-k} = 0$$

for example, the famous Fibonacci sequence is the solution to the following recurrence relation:

$$a_n = 1\cdot a_{n-1} + 1 \cdot a_{n-2}$$

There exist very many ways to solve these.

---

But, what if the $c_k$ are allowed to be functions of $n$ ?

$$a_{n} - \sum_k c_k(n)a_{n-k} = 0$$

How could we approach such a problem?

A simple example could be

$$a_n = n \cdot a_{n-1}$$

Well one obvious solution assuming $a_1 = 1$ is the super well known factorial function $a_n = n! = 1\cdot 2\cdots n$. ( Just to illustrate the usefulness and relevance of the construction. )

Comment: Problems like these are often solved using _generating functions_. I can recommend generatingfunctionology as an introduction: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf.

Comment: One idea from the Fibonacci sequence is, that they form a linear space. Then one needs from somewhere a basis (simple representation) that one knows in recursion free form. For the F. s. you more or less can guess that two dimensional basis (a power law). Then you try to express F(1) and F(2) as a linear combination, so you get the "bases" of the power law. It seems to me the dimension of the space is in your case $k+1$. But that only works when  the coefficients are not functions of $n$.

Comment: Thank you @orlp I just realized it from another almost simultaneous question.

Comment: This seems to have been addressed here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X97959035 (but I didn't read the paper).

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Wow that indexing was a bit nonintuitive, but the companion matrices sure awoke some thoughts.

Comment: Yes it has nothing to do with economics, but I don't really see the need to scratch the linear algebra tag.

Comment: @mathreadler I don't think linear algebra is *essential* to the problem even though some answers might make use of it. Especially because you are asking about non-linear recurrence relations.

Comment: @TrevorGunn don't get fooled by the name linear algebra, it can do quite some non-linear stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** To have response to this question, you can follow the case in differential equation too. If we be able to find a solution to the generalized recursive equation, we will find a solution to the following generalized differential equation:

$$y^{(n)}(x)-\sum_kg(x)y^{(k)}(x) = 0$$

Comment: Yep you are right, but I don't see how it helps so much. Feel free to expand with some method to solve the mentioned differential equation if you want.

Answer (score 0):

One numerical way to do it is to simply insert the function values into a matrix:

$$M=\left[\begin{array}{cccccccc}1&0&0&0&0&0\\-c_1(1)&1&0&0&0&0\\-c_2(2)&-c_1(2)&1&0&0&0\\-c_3(3)&-c_2(3)&-c_1(3)&1&0&0\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\\-c_m(m)&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&-c_1(m)&1\end{array}\right]$$

And then to solve the matrix equation system $$\bf Ma = 0 \Leftrightarrow a_o = \min_a\left\{\|Ma\|_2^2\right\}$$ subject to whatever  conditions we may have. Conditions can be incorporated for example as cost terms in the above least squares minimization.